# How do I run the following script from my articles page?

Tags: php, wp-query

(Hueman Theme)

I made my articles page (they are always sorted by default by date of publication) but I would like to sort my articles
based on the new custom fields I created with the Advanced Custom Fields plugin.
(I can see these fields in my admin dashboard (articles) (the new fields have been added and filled in).

To create the script, I searched the Net!!! and I was inspired by examples and I created the following script,
I inserted it in my page with shortcode widget but **how to activate it**??? or should I use another widget?
Already, is my script correct? , or are some instructions missing? (because I only started a few months ago...;-)) )

and **if possible I would like to activate it on my page from for example a radio button or something of the same type, is it possible?**
Thank you very much for your advice!

```
enter code here:
```

$query_args = array(
'post_type' => 'post',
'category_name' => 'course',
'order' => 'DESC',
'orderby'   => 'meta_value_num',
'meta_key' => ' number_runners',
'posts_per_page' => 5
);
$query = new WP_Query( $query_args );

Comment: Hello!,still no ideas...???

Comment: Bonjour toujours pas d'idées...???

Comment: Hello, Apparently no one has the solution...??? ;-))

Comment: Bonjour,  Apparemment cela n'inspire pas beaucoup de monde...??!!!  Pourtant j'essaie juste de trier mes articles sur des champs personnalisés...est-ce impossible ?